# Execute a build-in PHP server file with Docker

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I have a php application in Github, and I want to create a Docker image to, automaticaly, clone this application and run a custom server php file (react-php implemented).

This is my point of start.

```
FROM php:7.1-cli

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        libzip-dev \
        zip \
  && docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip \
  && docker-php-ext-install zip bcmath

RUN apt-get install -y \
        git-core \
        curl && \
    git clone https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git myfolder && \
    cd myfolder && \
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && \
    php composer.phar install

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["php bin/server"]
```

This code allows me to build the image, but when I run this image in a container, then I'm not being able to execute the file.

> /usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint: 9: exec: php bin/server: not
>   found

Maybe it's because I don't barely understand some bases of Docker, but it's getting hard for me to make this happen.

Any help on that, please?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official docker documentation for CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd), you should try to modify the last line of your Dockerfile to either `CMD php bin/server` or `CMD ["php", "bin/server"]`

Furthermore if you want your commands to be executed with a relative path, you should consider [setting the working directory](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) with the `WORKDIR directory` command before using RUN, CMD, ENTRYPOINT, COPY or ADD.